# Find the points of a hyperboloid where the tangent plane is parallel to a plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, hyperbolic-functions, tangent-line

Find the points on the hyperboloid $9x^2−45y^2+5z^2=45$ 
where the tangent plane is parallel to the plane $x+5y−2z=7.$

Much appreciate if someone could solve this question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

For the surface $f(x,y,z)=9x^2−45y^2+5z^2=45$ evaluate

$$\nabla f(x,y,z)=(f_x,f_y,f_z)$$

which is orthogonal to $f$ in $P(x,y,z)$ and compare with the normal vector of the given plane $(1,5,-2)$.